# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when trying to delete from an @FXML TableView

Tags: java, tableview

I don't understand why this method wont work because it worked literally three days ago. Whenever I try to use the method(press the button), The database operations work fine but the program throws an error whenever I try to remove from the actual table view so that the user wont see that row anymore. I added a filtered list to the initialize method and i am concerned that might be the cause of the problem. Here is my code:

Initialize Method:

```
    private void initialize()
    {
        ObservableList<BloomClient> clients = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        firstNames.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("FirstName"));
        lastNames.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("LastName"));
        phoneNumbers.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("PhoneNumber"));
        birthdays.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Birthday"));
        startDates.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("StartDate"));
        endDates.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ExpireDate"));
        try {
            clients = dBconnect.getClientList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FilteredList<BloomClient> filteredList = new FilteredList<BloomClient>(clients,b -> true);
        filteredSearch.textProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                filteredList.setPredicate(person ->
                {
                    if(newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty())
                        return true;//nothing in text field
                    String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
                    if (person.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter))
                        return true;//check first name
                    else if (person.getLastName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter))
                        return true;//check last name
                    else
                        return false;
                })
                ));
        SortedList<BloomClient> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);
        sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(clientList.comparatorProperty());
        clientList.setItems(sortedList);
    }



public void freezeAccount() throws SQLException, ParseException {
        BloomClient person = clientList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        dBconnect.sendToFreeze(person);//this works
        dBconnect.deleteClient(person);//this works
        clientList.getItems().remove(person);//java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        clientList.refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out in a way but would like a deeper explanation. I ended up instead of deleting from the clientList(TableView) I deleted directly from the clients(ObservableList) and made that variable global to be reached by other methods. I'm not sure of the reasoning behind the initial problem.

```
        BloomClient person = clientList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        dBconnect.deleteClient(person);
        clients.remove(person);
        clientList.refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. That makes more sense for working with JavaFX anyway. It's typically best to adjust the model being observed by the view. That's why I thought `clientList` was a list. :)

Comment: whatever the problem, refresh is most probably __not__ the answer (it's corner-case api which is extremely rarely needed) - which here doesn't seem to be the case: a transformationList is unmodifiable so you have to do the modifications on the backing list

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a guess. But it's possible that the `clientList` is a `List<>` type that was created using `Collections.unmodifiableList()`. When you try to modify one of those, an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown.

> public static  List unmodifiableList(List<? extends T> list)
>
> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows
> modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.
> Query operations on the returned list "read through" to the specified
> list, and attempts to modify the returned list, whether direct or via
> its iterator, result in an UnsupportedOperationException.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-

Comment: clientList is a TableView<Type>